# Remove "searchinterneat-a.akamaihd.net" Browser Hijack Malware

Tags: malware, spyware

I just recently download imgburn and got this browser hijack malware that when using Chrome, it redirects to Yahoo! search with "searchinterneat-a.akamaihd.net" in the URL. Sometimes it doesn't redirect but 4/5 times it does. It is a pretty smart too and I haven't been able to remove it.

I Googled some guides but they do not work. There is a particular guide that instructed to remove the user from Chrome but this will remove all my data and I do not want to do that. Is there an alternative? I have tried uninstalling the malicious programs and removed some stuff from the registry but to no avail.

**Update:** It is not really a fix but it solved the problem. I exported all my bookmarks and some data then I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled.

Comment: [(Solved) Attack of the "searchinterneat-a.akamaihd.net"](https://malwaretips.com/threads/attack-of-the-searchinterneat-a-akamaihd-net.52901/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks but it appears the fix was made for that particular user's system setup but I will look into it more.

Comment: The Q&A format is designed around questions being just questions and solutions being answers.  The posts are indexed that way so others with a similar problem can search the answers.  Can you move your update into an answer?  In two days, you will be able to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by doing a workaround. I exported all my data from Chrome and uninstalled it. Reinstalled and everything is back to normal. I suggest looking into the link in the original question comment and downloading software to prevent future exploits.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [adwcleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/). It's a rather easy to use, and powerful, malware/hijacker/adware removal tool. Also check your [DNS settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings#1TC=windows-7). They should be assigned automatically, but I've seen several cases where, along with this hijacker, the DNS has been changed to an IP from some random data center in the Middle East.

Comment: ADwcleaner did not detect anything. I will try checking DNS settings.

Comment: It's quite odd that ADW didn't detect it, I've seen several cases of it at my workplace and all of them have been fixed through ADW... Have you tried any other browser to see if it exists in them (i.e. Internet Explorer, Firefox)?

Comment: No i havent tried other browers. this malware is pretty smart IMO.

Comment: Try another browser, it could be limited to Chrome. Also check your [browser plugins](http://www.howtogeek.com/139916/how-to-view-and-disable-installed-browser-plug-ins-in-any-browser/) and disable anything that's suspicious.

Comment: I believe it is only limited to Chrome because I just tried with IE. I did also disable all browser plugins prior to asking the question.